# What is wrong with this python script?

Tags: python

```
x = object()
y = object()

x_list = [x * 10]
y_list = [y * 10]
big_list = [[x_list * 10], [y_list * 10]]

print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_lst))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10
    print("Almsot there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10
    print("Great!")
```

The error I'm getting says:

> File "/Users/sebastian/Desktop/python/test2.py", line 12
>       if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(x) == 10
>                                                        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: You need to finish the `if` statement lines with a colon, `:`

Comment: @L_Church: try again...

Comment: As user said, the arrow is there for a reason. It tells you where it thinks a syntax error has occurred. please listen to the error!

Answer (score 2):

[Syntax if statment python](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/ifstatements.html)

```
if condition:
    #do something
elif another_condition:  # This elif clause is optional.
     #do something
else:  # This is optional too.
    #do something
```

In your case you forgot `:` :

```
if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10: #<- put ':' here
    print("Almsot there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10: #<- put ':' here
    print("Great!")
```

Next time, fallow what the error says, a syntax error at the end of your `if` statment.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:` to the end of the `if` statements, like:

```
x = object()
y = object()

x_list = [x * 10]
y_list = [y * 10]
big_list = [[x_list * 10], [y_list * 10]]

print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_lst))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Almsot there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Great!")
```

That is [basic Python syntax](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html#simple-if-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Three syntax errors, you forgot the : at the end of your if statement and wrote x_lst instead of x_list and finally if you want to create a list of size 10, do  [x]*10

x = object()
    y = object()

```
x_list = [x]*10
y_list = [y]*10
big_list = [[x_list * 10], [y_list * 10]]

print("x_list contains %d objects" % len(x_list))
print("y_list contains %d objects" % len(y_list))
print("big_list contains %d objects" % len(big_list))

if x_list.count(x) == 10 and y_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Almsot there...")
if big_list.count(x) == 10 and big_list.count(y) == 10:
    print("Great!")
```